# Spring WS - JMS backed endpoint - When endpoint not found

Tags: exception, jms, spring-ws, endpoint

I have a Spring WS Endpoint which gets the payload from a JMS Queue. I use annotation based routing on my endpoint [based on payload root].

If for whatever reason, the routing doesn't happen [due to a typo etc], I only see a warning that there is "No Endpoint Found for Request SAAJSoapMessage". The main issue here is the message is lost! In my case, I would like an exception to be raised and fore the message to go to a Dead Letter Queue. The reliability is super critical here. What's the best way to achieve this. Here is my config:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616?jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries=5" />
</bean>

<bean id="cachingConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="profiler.request.queue" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"></property>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="local.transactionManager" />
    <property name="messageListener">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.ws.transport.jms.WebServiceMessageListener">
            <property name="messageFactory" ref="messageFactory" />
            <property name="messageReceiver" ref="messageDispatcher" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="local.transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <!-- can also refer to amq.connectionFactory -->
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="myRequestQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="my.request.queue" />
</bean>
<bean id="messageDispatcher"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher">

    <property name="endpointExceptionResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="util.EndpointExResolver"></bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```